# Plain image uploading - no links, no classes, no sizes

Tags: images

When I upload a photo into the post it turns out like this

```
<img src="http://localhost:8888/mg/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/sc5.jpg" alt="" width="240" height="240" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-245" />
```

Is there a way so it will just look like this?

```
<img src="http://localhost:8888/mg/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/sc5.jpg">
```

Comment: Can you give us some more information on why you want to do this? These attributes have a good reason for being there and make sense almost always.

Comment: I don't want a height of width of my images since all of them are responsive and change in size depending on screen size. I don't need any classes on my images either - the site is really simple.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good answer to this question here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-change-img-tag-html/

His second example is pretty much what you're looking for. Let me know if you need any further help with this.

The main chunk from that answer that concerns you is this:

```
function image_tag($html, $id, $alt, $title) {
    return preg_replace(array(
            '/'.str_replace('//','//',get_bloginfo('url')).'/i',
            '/s+width="d+"/i',
            '/s+height="d+"/i',
            '/alt=""/i'
        ),
        array(
            '',
            '',
            '',
            'alt="' . $title . '"'
        ),
        $html);
}
add_filter('get_image_tag', 'image_tag', 0, 4);
```

In your case, you'll want the `alt="' . $title . '"` bit to just be `''` like the strings above it.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE Jack! You're new so just one simple info: Please at least include the general idea of what is behind the link in your answer, otherwise when the link dies your response becomes useless. Have a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer for details

Comment: Thanks, but this changes it to look like this?

Comment: <a href="http://localhost:8888/mg/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/sc1.jpg"></a>